# Get value of element which is added by Javascript in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, controls

I have a web form in which I generate certain text box and dropdown dynamically and hence they do not have controls.
The html code looks like

```
<table id="tblcomponent">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name                            
                    </td>
                    <td>Type
                    </td>
                    <td>Stock
                    </td>
                    <td>Color
                    </td>
                    <td>Finishing
                    </td>
                    <td>Qty
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="Name" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Type">
                            <option>Type1</option>
                            <option>Type2</option>
                            <option>Type3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Stock">
                            <option>Stock1</option>
                            <option>Stock2</option>
                            <option>Stock3</option>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Color">
                            <option>Color1</option>
                            <option>Color2</option>
                            <option>Color3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Finishing">
                            <option>Finishing1</option>
                            <option>Finishing2</option>
                            <option>Finishing3</option>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <input type="number" name="Qty" />

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        <button type="button" onclick="AddRow("tblcomponent")" cursor: pointer;">Add</button>                     
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Everytime you click on the add button it generates a similar row by adding within the table element. Now I am trying to get the value of all rows but not sure how to use `Request.Form[]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make the entire table run server side through an asp:table. If you give the table an ID and set runat="server" you will be able to take care of all the events through server side code without having to parse through the information with javascript. Make your "Add" button a server side event along with whatever the event is that you need to parse through the table. If you need to do client side coding give the regular HTML table a id and parse through it using jQuery using something like $("#YourTableID")[0].rows[index].cells[index].outerText.